# Why input value on spark UI is less when we use more nodes and the shuffle value remains equal?

Tags: apache-spark

I run some queries on spark with just one node and then with 4 nodes. And in the spark:4040 UI I see something that I am not understanding. For example after executing a query with 4 nodes and check the results in the spark UI, in the "input" tab appears 2,8gb, so spark read 2,8gb from hadoop.

The same query on hadoop with just one node in local mode appears 7,3gb, the spark read 7,3GB from hadoop. But this value shouldnt be equal? For example the value of shuffle remains +- equal in one node vs 4. Why the input value doesn't stay equal? The same amount of data must be read from the hdfs, so I am not understanding. Do you know?

Single node:

[image]

Below the same query on multinode, as you can see input is less but the shuffle remains +- icual, do you know why?
[image]

Comment: You will have to be more descriptive with what you are asking. I can't assume things and answer.

Comment: Im asking when I execute the same query using 1 worker I get for exampe in input 7GB. If I execute the same query with 3 Workers I get 2,5GB  on the input tab. But the shuffle remains +- the same in the query execution either I use 1 or 3 workers. And Im not understanding why the shuffle reamins icual and the input stays different.

Comment: Can you attach snapshots of what difference you are talking about?

Comment: I update the question with that.

Comment: Thanks, What is the Spark version you are using, please share code snippet that you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Input is the size of data that your spark job is ingesting. For example, it can be data that each map task you may have defined is using.

Shuffling means the reallocation of data between multiple Spark stages. "Shuffle Write" is the sum of all written serialized data on all executors before transmitting (normally at the end of a stage) and "Shuffle Read" means the sum of read serialized data on all executors at the beginning of a stage.

Comment: Thanks for your help. But so the input should not be always icual regardless of the number of machines used to process the query like shuffle?

Comment: It should be but there are many bugs already logged about input data dependency in SPARK older version, make sure you are on latest one.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are talking about input tab in jobs. It could be a cumulative storage. Please check input in executor tab as well. As in 4 node it will have more executor the data will be distributed.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Yes Im talking about the input tab in jobs.  In the executors tab I have each worker with some input associated. But that sum of the inputs of all workers give 3GB. With one worker on local mode I have 7GB.